# GXT 3 - Sorting causes grid to horizontally scroll

Tags: gwt, gxt

If I try to sort a column that's out of view (I need to scroll on the right to see it)
then the column sorts but the table scrolls back to the left, (and the column i sorted is out of view again)

One can try this in the [Basic Gid](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:basicgrid) of the GXT showcase:
Just make the width of the columns larger so that the horizontal scroller shows up and then try to scroll at the end of the table and sort.

How to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it:
Override `onDataChanged` of `GridView` and set `preventScrollToTopOnRefresh` to true before sorting and then set it back to whatever it was. I wonder why this is not the default behaviour.

```
final GroupSummaryView<Row> view = new GroupSummaryView<Row>()
{
      protected void onDataChanged(StoreDataChangeEvent<Row> se) 
      {
          boolean b = preventScrollToTopOnRefresh;

          preventScrollToTopOnRefresh = true;

          super.onDataChanged(se);

          preventScrollToTopOnRefresh = b;            
      }
};

_table.setView(view);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in feature to prevent that behavior, so you have to write it yourself. You just need to store the scroll state before sorting and restore it after:

```
// save scroll state
final int scrollTop = getView().getScroller().getScrollTop();
final int scrollLeft = getView().getScroller().getScrollLeft();

// restore scroll state
getView().getScroller().setScrollTop(scrollTop);
getView().getScroller().setScrollLeft(scrollLeft);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it causes the grid to scroll back and forth.

Comment: That's true, unfortunately. I have to try your solution, it looks good so far ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Darek Kay : Thank You very much. I was having an issue of scroll down while changing the option by selecting value from `EditorTreeGrid`. Your suggesion worked for me. Here's what I did and worked for me :

```
    final int scrollTop = editorTreeGrid.getView().getScroller().getScrollTop();
    final int scrollLeft = ditorTreeGrid.getView().getScroller().getScrollLeft();

    editorTreeGrid.getView().refresh(true);

    editorTreeGrid.getView().getScroller().setScrollTop(scrollTop);
    editorTreeGrid.getView().getScroller().setScrollLeft(scrollLeft);
```